# Is FastClick needed for normal hyperlink when used in mobile webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, webkit, mobile-safari

The [FastClick](http://assanka.net/content/tech/2011/08/26/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/) library enhanced the responsiveness on JavaScript's `onClick` event when used under Webkit, but will it improve the  responsiveness of a normal hyperlink? (e.g. `<a href=''...`) ?

Comment: Did my answer not answer your question? If it didn't, please let me know why and I'll try and fill in any gaps that are missing :) And if my answer wasn't clear, by "it works on any HTMLElement" I meant "it should enhance the responsiveness of any HTMLElement". That's how the source code reads, anyways :) The only way for a "TRUE" answer is to test it out and get some metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal anchor element will navigate the browser when the `click` event is fired. On mobile that click registers 300ms after the `touchstart`. Using FastClick and a custom `window.location` change, will indeed speed things up.

*PS: I figured you are asking if default links, without custom JS handlers attached, will be faster with FastClick; **they won't**, you will have to add your own custom handler. You could easily do this by delegating from a HTML element high up, say `body`. You could use jQuery with the excellent: [`.on( events \[, selector\] \[, data\], handler(eventObject) )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)*

Comment: Based on this answer's advice, I used this short JQuery snippet to add FastClick.js to certain <a> elements, ones I marked with the `click-fast` class: `$('.click-fast').each(function() {new FastClick($(this));});`

Answer (score 6):

Looking through the FastClick code, it would seem it will work on ANY DOM object that inherits from HTMLElement (most all DOM objects) and supports the click event (and/or touch events if on a touch-enabled device).

This means that it should work on Anchor tags as well.

For reference, here is the only chunk of code in the FastClick source that does any kind of validation on the passed in object...

```
    if (!(layer instanceof HTMLElement)) {
        throw new TypeError('Layer must be instance of HTMLElement');
    }
```